# I'm getting a 500 status code response when I update ajax ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I want to update my user information but I'm getting an error

> 500 status code response

when I'm updating my data.

This is my code:

Context class:

public void Update(UserInformation model)
   {
       var user = _db.UserInfo
                .FirstOrDefault(m_id => m_id.Id == model.Id);

```
   _db.Update(user);
   _db.SaveChanges();
```

}

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostEdit(UserInformation userInformation)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }

    _ui_context.Update(userInformation);

    return new JsonResult("User Updated!");
}
```

My AJAX call:

```
if (action == "Update") {
    $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/UserInformation/PostEdit",
                data: $('#form_data').serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    clearFields();
                    $("#exampleModal").modal("hide");
                    loadUser();
                }
     });
}
```

Then this is my view on modal:

```
<form method="POST" id="form_data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="action_value" value="" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" id="txtFirst" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" id="txtLast" />
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Location" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Location" class="form-control" id="txtLocation" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Location" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image: 500 status code respone]

Thank you for your answer! Appreciate it much

Answer (score 0):

The 500 status that mean there is exception inside PostEdit() action. Please check your model userInformation pass into method  `_ui_context.Update(userInformation);`

You can change

```
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
return new JsonResult("Model is invalid");
}
```

Comment: I found it already my problem now is my data is not updating on database